Pulling out a new variable inside an integral
Suppose I have
$$f(t)\le\int_0^t\frac{(f(s)+c)}{g(s)}ds$$ where $c$ is constant.
Then, by writing $f(t)=\int_0^tf'(s)ds=\int_0^tdf(s)$
$=\int_0^td(f(s)+c)$, is it possible to write the above inequality as
$$\int_0^t\frac{d(f(s)+c)}{f(s)+c}\le\int_0^t\frac1{g(s)}ds$$
Assuming the conditions of fundamental theorem of calculus, continuity and non-vanishing of $f(t)+c$ are satisfied, is the above true.
I saw this procedure in a paper I was studying and was dumb founded by it. Any clarifications? Thanks beforehand.

$t$ appears as a limit of integration and a variable of integration. This is causing some ambiguity in my interpretations.

@SeanRoberson edited now. Thanks for pointing

Would you mind sharing the paper or reference you were studying? It's definitely not a standard move if it's valid (I don't see any obvious reason why it's true).

@AlexOrtiz The paper is this. Check if the paper accessible from your side?
